# localStorage and Null value

Tags: javascript, html, null, local-storage

I have this if statement:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('user') != null){
        alert('get values called from start. User stored: '+localStorage.getItem('user'));
        getValues();
    }
```

It's suppose to run getValues only when there is a user that's logged in. However it's running even though the user stored is null. As you can see in the image below, the user value is null so why is it running?

This is my site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/

[image]

Comment: Whatever you store in localStorage is a string. So you deal with a  *string* `"null"`, not with real `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I just stopped using null and went with a string. Fixed everything.